# Extracting a file name from a file path SQL Server CE

Tags: sql, substring

I have a file path in the database, which is SQL Server Compact Edition, as such:

C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\Test.doc
C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\Test2.doc
C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\Reports\Test.doc

As you can see the file name and folder structure can be different with each entry so I only want to show the text after the last '\'.

I'm so far experimenting with the substring but it doesn't seem to give me what I need:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(FileName,1, CHARINDEX('\', 0))
```

Comment: what database management system are you using? mysql, MS sql server, etc?

Comment: SQL Server Compact Edition

Comment: [this](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/how-to-extract-filename-from-path-using-sql-functions.aspx) might be useful

Comment: I get an error to say that reverse isn't supported in SQL server compact